# Is there an alternative to nltk in golang?

Tags: nlp, nltk, software-recommendation

Golang is one of my favourite languages and I want to use it for a personal NLP/ML project. Is golang's ecosystem good and rich enough for this?

Is there an alternative package for nltk in golang?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No. Not yet**

There is no single package in Golang, which acts as versatile as nltk for NLP. However, there are several packages which aim to do it.

Here is a compiled list of such packages: https://github.com/gopherds/resources/blob/master/tooling/README.md#nlp

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look into [this repository](https://github.com/jdkato/prose), it was recently announced in hacker news. I personally don't have experience using it, but the benchmarks look interesting:

> prose is a natural language processing library (English only, at the moment) in pure Go. It supports tokenization, segmentation, part-of-speech tagging, and named-entity extraction.